# (Libgdx) make everything in stage and spritebatch dark

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm developing a LibGDX game.
I came to a point where I would like to have all elements in my stage (several labels, buttons etc.) but also the things i draw onto the main spritebatch to get dark and not touchable for when a popup opens in which the user can interact.

Making the stage not respond to user input was very simple, by taking it out of the inputprocessor.

But how to make everything in the stage and the spriteBatch dark so that it becomes obvious to the user that he has to interact with the popup first.

I want it to be somewhat like this [image]

but with a LibGDX stage and spritebatch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you add 1x1 pixel transparent black image which is stretched to screen size before your popup, you dont need to change inputprocessor. Touchables of the actors under your transparent image automatically disabled. So you dont need to end and begin spritebatch again which is not good for performance.

So you can do this without changing spritebatch or using additional gl glear call by only adding a transparent area.

Comment: You mean a black pixel with about half opacity that should be drawn after the stage is drawn and after that the popup should be drawn?
I think I could still click through the image to the "behind" the half transparent pixel.

Comment: Yes, thats what i mean. stage hierarchy will be like that in your screenshot : ShowPopupButton -> transparent image -> popup widget

Comment: Okay i added the pixel thing and it works. Is there even an option from the spritebatch to now allow the user to click through things that it is drawn on or do I have to get the stage out of my inputmultiplexer to achieve what I want?

Comment: can you please check touchable field of your transparent image? if you set it to enabled, it should prevent you touch under the transparent area which means you have a modal popup.

Comment: I did neither find the option "touchable" for textures nor sprites.
an image has the .setTouchable(Touchable.enabled) option, but i can still click through it.
Which imagecontainer has that feature?

Comment: As far as i understand from your explanation, you are working with stage and scene2d (labels, buttons). So in scene2d there is Image actor you can use. I suggest you to use scene2d, stage and actors which ease your job if you don't

Comment: I do use Scene2D. It is still possible to click through a scene2D image though, even if you .setTouchable(Touchable.enabled). I got it working anyways by a bool check for if the popup is opened.
Accepted your answer, thx. :)